Problema con la API de Binance en Producción (Cifrado SHA-256), Laravel
necesito ayuda con un problema que me tiene bloqueado desde hace días.
Estoy desarrollando una integración con la API de Binance y me encuentro con un problema que no logro resolver. Espero que alguien aquí pueda darme una mano o alguna idea para seguir adelante. El problema está relacionado con la firma HMAC SHA-256 que Binance exige para autenticar las solicitudes. El comportamiento en producción y testing es inconsistente, y no sé dónde estoy fallando.
Contexto:
En el entorno de testing, la integración con la API de Binance funciona perfectamente. Puedo hacer llamadas a la API, enviar transacciones, recibir respuestas y todo parece estar en orden.
Sin embargo, cuando paso al entorno de producción, todas las solicitudes son rechazadas. Parece que el problema está en la firma (cifrado HMAC-SHA256), pero no logro entender por qué falla en producción si en testing todo está bien.
Lo que ya revisé:
Documentación de Binance: Según la documentación, Binance requiere que las firmas de autenticación se generen utilizando HMAC SHA-256. Estoy seguro de que NO estoy usando este algoritmo para firmar las solicitudes porque me genera error en su defecto uso sha512 que funciona genial.
Proceso de firma: Para generar la firma:
Organizo los parámetros en un string de consulta.
Utilizo la clave secreta de la API para crear un hash HMAC con el algoritmo SHA-512.
Finalmente, envío este hash como parte de la solicitud.
En el entorno de testing, este proceso parece funcionar perfectamente. Las transacciones son aceptadas y la API responde correctamente.
Llaves de API: He revisado varias veces que estoy utilizando las claves API correctas en producción. Es decir, no estoy reutilizando las claves de testing por error. Cada entorno tiene sus propias claves, y en producción estoy usando las adecuadas.
Parámetros de la solicitud: Todos los parámetros que envío a la API están correctamente organizados y en el orden especificado por Binance. No he visto ninguna diferencia en este aspecto entre testing y producción.
Entorno de producción:
El entorno de producción está configurado correctamente, con acceso a la librería de cifrado adecuada para generar los hashes HMAC-SHA256.
También estoy utilizando HTTPS en producción, por lo que no debería haber problemas relacionados con la seguridad del transporte.
Posible causa del problema:
Mi sospecha es que el problema podría estar en cómo se genera la firma en producción, ya que las solicitudes se rechazan. No sé si hay algún detalle en la generación del hash que estoy pasando por alto. He revisado varias veces el proceso, pero no logro identificar si hay alguna diferencia entre cómo se hace en testing y producción.
Otra posible causa que he pensado es si la configuración del servidor en producción puede estar interfiriendo de alguna manera con el proceso de cifrado, aunque he verificado las versiones de las librerías de cifrado, y parecen estar actualizadas y funcionando correctamente.
Lo que necesito saber:
¿Hay alguna diferencia entre cómo Binance valida las firmas HMAC-SHA512 en producción y en testing? He revisado la documentación, pero no menciona diferencias entre estos entornos.
¿Es posible que haya alguna restricción de seguridad adicional en el entorno de producción de Binance que esté causando que rechacen mis solicitudes?
Logs y Errores:
Desafortunadamente, los logs de Binance no me ofrecen mucha información más allá de que la firma es inválida. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de obtener más detalles sobre por qué una firma en particular es rechazada y por tanto los registros no llego a verlos en mi log.
Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\Gateways\BinancePayService;
use App\Models\Wallet;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\Deposit;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class BinancePayController extends Controller
{
    protected $binancePayService;

    public function __construct(BinancePayService $binancePayService)
    {
        $this->binancePayService = $binancePayService;
    }

   public function createOrder(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'amount' => 'required|numeric|min:0.01',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    ]);

    try {
        $merchantTradeNo = 'GUBT' . $request->user_id . 'time' . time();
        $orderData = $this->binancePayService->createOrder(
            $merchantTradeNo, 
            $request->amount,
            route('payment.success'),  // URL de éxito
            route('payment.cancel'),   // URL de cancelación
            'USDT'  // o la moneda que estés usando
        );
        
        return response()->json($orderData);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Error creating Binance Pay order', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}

public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('Webhook received', ['data' => $request->all(), 'headers' => $request->headers->all()]);

    try {
        if (!$this->verifyWebhookSignature($request)) {
            Log::error('Invalid webhook signature');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid signature'], 400);
        }

        $data = $request->all();
        Log::info('Webhook data', $data);

        if ($data['bizType'] === 'PAY' && $data['bizStatus'] === 'PAY_SUCCESS') {
            $merchantTradeNo = $data['merchantTradeNo'];
            $amount = $data['orderAmount'];
            
            $userId = $this->extractUserId($merchantTradeNo);
            Log::info('Extracted user ID', ['user_id' => $userId, 'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);
            
            if (!$userId) {
                Log::error('Failed to extract user ID from merchantTradeNo', ['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid merchantTradeNo'], 400);
            }

            DB::beginTransaction();
            
            try {
                $wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $userId)->lockForUpdate()->first();
                
                if (!$wallet) {
                    Log::error('Wallet not found', ['user_id' => $userId]);
                    throw new \Exception('Wallet not found for user ID: ' . $userId);
                }
                
                $oldBalance = $wallet->balance;
                $wallet->balance += $amount;
                $wallet->balance_deposit_rollover += $amount;
                $wallet->save();
                
                Log::info('Wallet updated', [
                    'user_id' => $wallet->user_id,
                    'wallet_id' => $wallet->id,
                    'old_balance' => $oldBalance,
                    'new_balance' => $wallet->balance,
                    'amount_added' => $amount
                ]);
                
                $deposit = Deposit::create([
                    'payment_id' => $data['bizIdStr'] ?? $merchantTradeNo,
                    'user_id' => $wallet->user_id,
                    'amount' => $amount,
                    'type' => 'binance_pay',
                    'status' => 1,
                    'currency' => $wallet->currency,
                    'symbol' => $wallet->symbol,
                ]);
                
                Log::info('Deposit record created', ['deposit_id' => $deposit->id]);
                
                DB::commit();
                
                Log::info('Payment processed successfully', [
                    'user_id' => $wallet->user_id,
                    'wallet_id' => $wallet->id,
                    'amount' => $amount,
                    'new_balance' => $wallet->balance
                ]);
                
                return response()->json(['success' => true]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                DB::rollBack();
                Log::error('Error processing payment', ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'user_id' => $userId]);
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Error processing payment: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
            }
        } else {
            Log::info('Webhook received but not processed (not a successful payment)');
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Webhook received but not processed']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Unhandled exception in webhook', ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()]);
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal server error: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}

private function extractUserId($merchantTradeNo)
{
    $start = strpos($merchantTradeNo, 'GUBT') + 4;
    $end = strpos($merchantTradeNo, 'time');
    if ($start !== false && $end !== false) {
        return substr($merchantTradeNo, $start, $end - $start);
    }
    return null;
}

public function checkOrderStatus($merchantTradeNo)
{
    try {
        $status = $this->binancePayService->checkOrderStatus($merchantTradeNo);
        return response()->json($status);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}

public function checkPaymentStatus(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'merchantTradeNo' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    try {
        $status = $this->binancePayService->queryOrder($request->merchantTradeNo);
        
        if ($status['status'] === 'PAY_SUCCESS') {
            // Actualizar la wallet y crear el registro de depósito
            $this->processSuccessfulPayment($status);
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Payment successful']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'pending', 'message' => 'Payment not completed yet']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Error checking payment status', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error checking payment status'], 500);
    }
}

private function processSuccessfulPayment($paymentData)
{
    $userId = $this->extractUserId($paymentData['merchantTradeNo']);
    $amount = $paymentData['orderAmount'];

    DB::transaction(function () use ($userId, $amount, $paymentData) {
        $wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $userId)->lockForUpdate()->firstOrFail();
        $wallet->balance += $amount;
        $wallet->balance_deposit_rollover += $amount;
        $wallet->save();

        Deposit::create([
            'payment_id' => $paymentData['bizIdStr'] ?? $paymentData['merchantTradeNo'],
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'type' => 'binance_pay',
            'status' => 1,
            'currency' => $wallet->currency,
            'symbol' => $wallet->symbol,
        ]);
    });
}

private function verifyWebhookSignature(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('Verifying webhook signature', [
        'env' => config('app.env'),
        'headers' => $request->headers->all()
    ]);

    if (config('app.env') !== 'production') {
        if ($request->header('X-Webhook-Test-Token') === config('binance_pay.test_webhook_token')) {
            Log::info('Using test token for verification in non-production environment');
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    try {
        $result = $this->binancePayService->verifyWebhookSignature($request->header(), $request->getContent());
        Log::info('Signature verification result', ['result' => $result]);
        return $result;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Error verifying signature', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        return false;
    }
}

private function isTestRequest(Request $request)
{
    $testToken = config('binance_pay.test_webhook_token');
    
    // Verifica si existe un token de prueba configurado y si coincide con el proporcionado en la solicitud
    return $testToken && $request->header('X-Webhook-Test-Token') === $testToken;
}

    
    public function paymentSuccess(Request $request)
{
    // Aquí puedes agregar lógica adicional si es necesario
    return view('payment.success');
}

public function paymentCancel(Request $request)
{
    // Aquí puedes agregar lógica adicional si es necesario
    return view('payment.cancel');
}
}

Mi service:
<?php
namespace App\Services\Gateways;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class BinancePayService
{
    protected $client;
    protected $apiKey;
    protected $secretKey;
    protected $apiUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiKey = config('binance_pay.api_key');
        $this->secretKey = config('binance_pay.secret_key');
        $this->apiUrl = config('binance_pay.api_url');
        $this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->apiUrl]);
    }

    public function createOrder($merchantTradeNo, $totalFee, $successUrl, $cancelUrl, $currency = 'USDT')
    {
        $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
        $payload = [
            'env' => [
                'terminalType' => 'WEB'
            ],
            'merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo,
            'orderAmount' => $totalFee,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'goods' => [
                'goodsType' => '01',
                'goodsCategory' => '7000',
                'referenceGoodsId' => 'GUBT001',
                'goodsName' => 'GUBT Credits',
            ],
            'returnUrl' => $successUrl,
            'cancelUrl' => $cancelUrl,
        ];
        $jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);
        
        $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $jsonPayload);
        try {
            $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                    'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                    'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                    'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
                ],
                'body' => $jsonPayload
            ]);
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            
            if ($result['status'] === 'SUCCESS') {
                return $result['data'];
            } else {
                Log::error('Binance Pay order creation failed', $result);
                throw new \Exception('Failed to create Binance Pay order: ' . ($result['errorMessage'] ?? 'Unknown error'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'payload' => $payload,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

public function queryOrder($merchantTradeNo)
{
    $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
    $payload = json_encode(['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);

    $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload);

    try {
        $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order/query', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
            ],
            'body' => $payload
        ]);

        $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        
        if ($result['status'] === 'SUCCESS') {
            return $result['data'];
        } else {
            Log::error('Binance Pay order query failed', $result);
            throw new \Exception('Failed to query Binance Pay order: ' . $result['errorMessage']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        throw $e;
    }
}

 public function checkOrderStatus($merchantTradeNo)
    {
        $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->generateNonce();
        $payload = json_encode(['merchantTradeNo' => $merchantTradeNo]);

        $signature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload);

        try {
            $response = $this->client->post('/binancepay/openapi/v2/order/query', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'BinancePay-Timestamp' => $timestamp,
                    'BinancePay-Nonce' => $nonce,
                    'BinancePay-Certificate-SN' => $this->apiKey,
                    'BinancePay-Signature' => $signature,
                ],
                'body' => $payload
            ]);

            return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Binance Pay API request failed', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    

    public function verifyWebhookSignature($headers, $payload)
    {
        $timestamp = $headers['Binancepay-Timestamp'][0] ?? '';
        $nonce = $headers['Binancepay-Nonce'][0] ?? '';
        $signature = $headers['Binancepay-Signature'][0] ?? '';

        if (empty($timestamp) || empty($nonce) || empty($signature)) {
            Log::error('Missing required headers for signature verification', [
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'nonce' => $nonce,
                'signature' => $signature
            ]);
            return false;
        }

        $calculatedSignature = $this->generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload);

        $result = hash_equals($signature, $calculatedSignature);

        if (!$result) {
            Log::error('Webhook signature verification failed', [
                'calculated' => $calculatedSignature,
                'received' => $signature,
                'payload' => $payload
            ]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function generateNonce()
    {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    }

    private function generateSignature($timestamp, $nonce, $payload)
    {
        $payloadToSign = $timestamp . "\n" . $nonce . "\n" . $payload . "\n";
        return strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $payloadToSign, $this->secretKey));
    }
}



